# Javascript : How to access a table inside a frame?

Tags: javascript

To access the value of an ID we can use :
    document.getElementById(ID).value. 
But I have a problem of accessing an ID in a table. There is a frame inside a table. The content of the frame is a table also because I want to scroll up and down the table.

main.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function show_name()
 {
   alert(document.getElementById("name1").value);
 }
</script>


<table id="table1">
 <tr>
   <td>
      <div id="mydiv">
        <!-- the ajax func call myframe.php and pu result here -->  
      </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Show Name" onClick="show_name()">
```

myframe.php :

```
<iframe height="500px" height="400px" src="table2.php"></iframe>
```

Below is table2.php. It produces a table interactively based on a parameter passed into it. And of course the feedback inserted into "mydiv".

```
<?php
 // mysql_connect();
 // mysq_query....
?>

 <table id="table2">
 <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="name1" value="john">
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

The code run very good, and everything come up into the page correctly. By I want to do someting with an object inside the frame, but how to access it ?

So far pushing the button give nothing, that means the object can not be accessed by the code. Of course, there will be more meaningfull process rather than just alert a name.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

To access the element inside the iframe:

```
window.frames[1].document.getElementById('name1');
```